# How to create branch-specific files on GitHub

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I would like to have branch-specific files with the same name. I need to be able to merge from my development branch to master without changes made in this file.

For example:
Let's assume that I would like to have two different `readme.md` files. In one I would like to have content: `MASTER` and in another `DEV`. But if I try to do it, while creating pull-request GitHub will try to merge this file, which is exactly my problem. I don't want GitHub to merge this file each time I make changes.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Are that files already commited?

Comment: @grimsock: yes, as I mentioned in edit, in my case I've got two files like this: readme.md and CI configuration files, so obviously they need to be commited

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say `project` is a name of the branch to be merged, and `README.md` is a name of the file that keep branch specific information.

I would suggest the following steps:

1. Merge project branch, but make sure changes are not committed, and not fast-forwarded

   ```
   $ git merge --no-commit --no-ff project
   ```
2. Unstage `README.md` file and checkout its current branch version

   ```
   $ git checkout HEAD -- README.md
   ```
3. Complete merge

   ```
   $ git commit
   ```

Also, it makes sense to install merge driver that will keep branch specific version of a file in case of merge conflict. In such case, you will never need to resolve conflicts in branch specific files manually.

Such merge driver is usually called `ours` and defined as:

```
$ git config --global merge.ours.driver true
```

Now, you can specify in `.gitattributes` file, when this merger should be used.

In our case, it is needed to add the following rule to `.gitattributes` and commit it:

`README.md merge=ours`

Comment: do need to do this everytime i merge