# Branch specific lines in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

Sorry that my question is so vague, but I don't really know how to describe the situation best.

In my repository the `README` file contains a link, which has the branch name `master` or `develop` in it for the respective branches (only those two branches are affected, I don't really care how it is handled for different branches). What I want now, is that if I merge `develop` into `master` this difference is preserved.

What I did up to now, was using

```
git merge --no-commit develop
```

And manually fix the link. The problem here is, that `develop` has then an independent history of `master`. Thus, `git describe` from the `develop` branch doesn't include the latest tag on master. I use this however for versioning, so it is essential to have this. A work around is to then merge `master` back into `develop`

```
git merge --no-commit master
```

This however causes a messy history, as I have plenty of these empty back-merges.

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067481/how-to-create-branch-specific-files-on-github), where I add `README.rst merge=ours`. However, this ignores **all** changes to `README` thus I would have to manually update the `README` file.

I don't really know if there is a suitable approach. Is there a way I can tell GitHub to ignore the links (e.g. via a regular expression)? Or maybe some command that expands into the branch name?

Comment: Checkout a branch, edit the file, commit the change?

Comment: I haven't really understood why you use `git merge` with `--no-commit`. Merging does not mean that for sure you get all the changes from another branch. You may select to drop a conflicting change in your merge commit. Doing this will prevent any problems on the next merges.

Comment: I chose `--no-commit` not to overwrite the link in `master`. Just committing does not produce an error. It just overwrites the older version with the newer. So if I understand you right, you propose to make a commit to `master` changing the link there, thus provoking a merge conflict on future merges? But wouldn't that diverge the histories of the branches? Thus, `git describe` on `develop` would never reflect any tags in `master` in the future?

Comment: Just to mention, `git describe` behavior is as expected and is not related to your issue. merging `develop` branch into the `master` branch doesn't mean to merge `master` into `develop`.  see the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (quite) get what you want.  You might be able to get what you need, depending on where you need it.  Consider using a *smudge filter* to alter the file as it gets checked out.  You need a corresponding *clean filter* to remove the smudging, so that what's in the actual commits is un-smudged.

For more about setting up smudge and clean filters, see [the `gitattributes` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html).

#### Background

First, remember that a branch *name* is just a moveable pointer to a (single) commit.  There is something else that people also refer to using the word *branch*, which is: *a series of commits ended by a particular commit.*  For more about this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

In general, what Git does is *add commits*.  You check out some branch name:

```
$ git checkout master
```

and then do some work (on files in your *work-tree*, which you then copy into the *staging area* aka *index* using `git add` to overwrite the copies that were already in the index but match the current commit—we'll come back to all this in a bit):

```
... edit ...
$ git add README.rst
```

Eventually, you run `git commit`, which:

- collects a log message from you;
- packages up *all* the files that are in the index right now; and
- uses those (plus your name and email and the time) to make a new commit.

The new commit's parent commit is the *commit* you checked out, when you ran `git checkout master`.  The *new* commit becomes the one at the tip of the *branch* you chose, when you ran `git checkout master`.  So the *name* `master` now points to the *new* commit, which points back to what was the `master` commit just a moment ago:

```
...  <-previous-tip-of-master  <-new-tip-of-master   <--master
```

You can only check out one branch at a time, and `git commit` makes its new commit on *that* branch—specifically, by making that *name* point to the new commit Git just made.  All other branch names are unchanged: they still point to some other commit(s).

Using `git merge` still just makes a new commit!  The difference between this new commit and other new commits made by `git commit` is that this new commit has *two* parents: it points back to the previous commit as usual, but it also points back to the commit you chose when you ran `git merge`.  In any case this new commit is only *on* the branch you're on:

```
...--B--...--o--C--M   <-- master
      \           /
       o--...-o--D   <-- develop
```

where `M` is the new merge commit.  This new merge commit has a snapshot of all files, just like every other commit has a snapshot of all files, so the `README.rst` file in `M` is built by doing something(s) with the snapshot in `C`—which was the tip of `master` a moment ago—and something(s) with the snapshot in `D`, which is still the tip of `develop`.  These "somethings" are based on how `C` and `D` have changed since the *merge base* commit version of `README.rst` that's in the snapshot in commit `B`.

#### Making use of this: smudge and clean filters

Now, along with this metadata about who made it, when, and with what log message, each *commit* simply records all the source files that were in the index / staging-area at the time you ran `git commit`.  What you get when you `git checkout <thing-that-specifies-commit>` is *derived from* this snapshot, but is not necessarily *the same as* this snapshot.

All of these details are important!  Git will extract the commit in `M` into the index / staging-area.  What's in this index / staging-area at this point *exactly matches* whatever is inside `M`.  But this isn't what you see in your *work-tree*.  What you see in your work-tree is obtained by running whatever Git copied into the index through any *smudge filter* you define.

The default smudge filter is basically "leave everything unchanged".  You can get end-of-line adjustments to happen at this point.  Technically this is separate from smudge filters, but it's all part of this smudging process.  If you use this default, what's in your work-tree matches what's in your index.

Suppose, though, that you define a smudge filter to apply specifically to `README.rst`.  Suppose further that you write this smudge filter to find the line with the link that is supposed to mention the branch, `master` or `develop`.  Write your smudge filter to *replace* this line with the *correct* link.  For instance, perhaps the line you commit should read:

```
blah blah link:!replace this part! blah
```

and your smudge filter says:

```
sed -e "s/!replace this part!/actual link using $branch/"
```

(using the Linux/Unix/GNU `sed` command, but you can write this however you like).  Make your smudge filter code figure out what branch name to use by, e.g., running `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.

This means that what's in the work-tree for file `README.rst` will no longer match what's actually *committed*.

To make this work properly, though, you need to make `git add` write, as the thing-to-be-committed, a line that reads:

```
blah blah link:!replace this part! blah
```

To do this automatically, write yourself a *clean* filter that finds the smudged line—however you choose to do that—and replaces it, e.g., using `sed`, with the `!replace this part!` text.

Now when you run:

```
$ git add README.rst
```

Git will run the work-tree file through your clean filter to get the version of `README.rst` to write into the index / staging-area.

This also works when merging: the merge will "see" the *cleaned* version of the file, and merge any changes you make, on either branch, using the cleaned text.  The "dirty" (smudged) version that has the actual link *appears only in the work-tree*.  It never goes into any commit.

Whether this does what you need depends on what reads the link.  If whatever reads the link, does so by extracting commits to a work-tree, and uses the smudge filter, than that thing reading the file will read the dirtied-up actual link.  If the thing reading the file somehow bypasses all of this and gets the raw committed content, it will see the "cleaned" link.

If you store the cleaned link as a version suitable for most uses, and only need the dirty version that points to `develop` instead of `master` when used out of the work-tree, this will work even for that case as well.