# How to have git auto-resolve a certain type of conflict automatically?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

At our company we have a proprietary xml configuration format that contains a 32-bit CRC at the end of the file in a comment like `<!--0x7A49-->`

Whenever a developer modifies this file, this CRC will also get updated, resulting in constant conflicts on this line when performing a rebase or merge.

The majority of the time, the merge would be able to happen automatically except for this one line, so it would great if we could somehow configure git to auto-resolve it.

The best solution would be able to automate updating the CRC after a merge takes place, because both copies will inevitably be invalid after the merge.

Comment: Consider using smudge and clean filters to avoid storing the CRC at all. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49636894/1256452 (which is a guide, not a solution)

Comment: Very interesting, I was not aware of this feature. I'll have to play around with it. Thanks!